# Using generic parameter in Redux Toolkit createSlice reducer with prepare?

Tags: typescript, generics, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to create a reducer in RTK that takes two arguments which share a generic type. However it seems impossible to share the generic type between the `reducer` and `prepare` functions.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve

```
type SetPayload<T> = {
    thingToBeSet: MyClass<T>;
    value: T;
}

export const mySlice = createSlice({
    name: 'mySlice',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        myReducer: {
            reducer: (state, action: PayloadAction<SetPayload<any>>) => {
                // Modify state here
            },
            prepare: <T>(thingToBeSet: MyClass<T>, value: T) => {
                return {
                    payload: { thingToBeSet, value }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As shown in the code above, my `prepare` function uses a generic parameter (as the type of some properties on thingToBeSet must match the type of value). However, this type parameter cannot be used for the type of `action` in the reducer function - I tried setting this to `any` which gives this error:

```
The types of 'payload.thingToBeSet' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'MyClass<never>' is not assignable to type 'MyClass<any>'.
          Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

As `any` cannot be converted to `T` - But how can I share `T` between both the reducer and prepare functions here?

What I think I want is to somehow create a generic object literal for the myReducer object, something like this (unfortunately not valid TS - is this possible?):

```
myReducer: <T> {
    reducer: (state, action: PayloadAction<SetPayload<T>>) => {
        // Modify state here
    },
    prepare: (thingToBeSet: MyClass<T>, value: T) => {
        return {
            payload: { thingToBeSet, value }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that is not possible. Those types are mapped internally to create a new action creator function - and mapped types cannot inherit generic functionality.

The best you could do would be to cast that action generator to your generic function type before you export it.

```
export const myReducer = slice.actions.myReducer as <T>(thingToBeSet: MyClass<T>, value: T) => PayloadAction<SetPayload<T>>)
```

Answer (score 2):

The eventual solution I used for this was to create the action manually outside of createSlice, and use extraReducers property for the reducer. Setting the `type` property on the function allows for automatic typing and similar usage to RTK. This is more verbose and not ideal, but it at least gives the correct typing, and implicit types in the reducer.

Action:

```
const myActionName = 'myAction';
export function myAction<T>(thingToBeSet: MyClass<T>, value: T): PayloadAction<SetPayload<T>> {
    return {
        type: myActionName,
        payload: { thingToBeSet, value }
    }
}
myAction.type = myActionName;
```

Reducer:

```
createSlice({
    ...
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder
            .addCase(myAction, (state, action) => {
                // Perform state changes
                // `state` and `action` have correct implicit types
                // (`action` is of type `PayloadAction<SetPayload<unknown>>`)
            })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create a helper custom hook, so I dispatch the actions through it. With that I was able to pass generic parameters.

```
const useProducerForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const setFormValue = <T extends DefaultForms>(
    form: T,
    value: ProducerFormState['data'][T]['value'],
  ) =>
    dispatch(
      setFormValueAction({
        form,
        value,
      }),
    );

  return {
    setFormValue,
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Any One using redux toolkit and he wants to update the state without creating reducer each time if you wana update the state , rather reducers will be created ounce by the wrapper function and one can update the state like below

```
const {inventoryState, inventoryActions} = inventoryStore()

useEffect(() => {
  inventoryActions.item.name.set("ITEM 101"); 
}, [state])
```

- No explicit reducer , reducer will be created implicitly
- Granular level updates
- When set is called it will dispatch those to store automatically
- Redux toolkit gives logs like InventorySlice/item.name
- link to follow : https://mohsin-ejaz.gitbook.io/redux/redux-easy

Comment: Please if you downgrade please give reason otherwise donot downgrade any post

Comment: Hi there @Mohsin Ejaz. Your post in not answering the question at all. He is asking about how to share the generic type between the reducer and prepare functions and you are explaining how to update the state without dispatching an action. You are not  using generics in your code.